# pygame: self.screen AttributeError: ... no attribute 'screen'

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to learn some pygame programming so i found the pivader project which should be a good start to learn python/pygame.
here the link: [pivaders](https://github.com/russb78/pivaders/blob/master/pivaders/pivaders.py)

So I dont want to make the whole game for now. I am just trying to get the Game-Menu done: that means I want the start-screen and after pushing SPACE I want to enter the ingame screen.
Here my Code

```
import pygame, random

RES = (800, 600)

class GameState:
    pass

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.font.init()
        self_screen = pygame.display.set_mode([RES[0], RES[1]])
        self.intro_font = pygame.font.Font(
            'data/Orbitracer.ttf', 72)
        self.intro_screen = pygame.image.load(
            '/home/pi/pivaders/data/graphics/start_screen.jpg')
        self.background = pygame.image.load(
            '/home/pi/pivaders/data/graphics/Space-Background.jpg')
        GameState.end_game = False
        GameState.start_screen = True


    def control(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                GameState.start_screen = False
                GameState.end_game = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN \
            and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                if GameState.start_screen:
                    GameState.start_screen = False
                    GameState.end_game = True
                else:
                    GameState.start_screen = True
        self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if self.keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            if GameState.start_screen:
                GameState.start_screen = False

    def splash_screen(self):
        while GameState.start_screen:
            self.screen.blit(self.intro_screen, [0, 0])
            self.screen.blit(self.intro_font.render(
                "PIVADERS", 1, WHITE), (265, 128))
            self.screen.blit(self.intro_font.render(
                "PRESS SPACE TO PLAY", 1, WHITE), (284, 191))
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.control()

    def refresh_screen(self):
        self.all_sprite_list.draw(self.screen)
        self.screen.blit(self.background, [0, 0])
        self.clock.tick(self.refresh_rate)

    def main_loop(self):
        while not GameState.end_game:
            while not GameState.start_screen:
                self.control()
                self.refresh_screen()
            self.splash_screen()
        pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pv = Game()
    pv.main_loop()
```

Now i get this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                  
File "/home/pi/pivaders/MenuTest.py", line 65, in <module>                     
pv.main_loop()
File "/home/pi/pivaders/MenuTest.py", line 60, in main_loop
self.splash_screen()
File "/home/pi/pivaders/MenuTest.py", line 42, in splash_screen
self.screen.blit(self.intro_screen, [0, 0])
AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'screen'
```

I found other questions about that Error and the screen / self.screen but i couldnt figure out how to solve my problem by using that new informations.
I dont know why the AttributeError: pops up here I never used the screen without self..

I already was here:
[How do I solve an attribute error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820344/how-do-i-solve-an-attribute-error)
https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/348024/global-name-screen-is-not-definedpygame

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your `__init__` method.

```
self_screen = pygame.display.set_mode([RES[0], RES[1]])
```

should be

```
self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode([RES[0], RES[1]])
```

Notice the difference between `self_screen` and `self.screen`.

Comment: Wow rly i checked it 2 hours and didnt saw this? Now i feel bad to post it here because of that. -Thanks for that quick check ^^

Answer (score 0):

Ok now i get the start_screen but the SPACE does not what i thought it does :3
i deleted the "refresh_screen" method because i guess its useless here. i also added the global variable "WHITE = (255, 255, 255)" because i forgott that. and of course i replaced self_screen with self.screen.
.
Now i have to figure out what is missing to change the picture by pushing SPACE. I will write another answer if i found it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now i have what i want to have. If i start, the start_screen comes in a window 800x600. After pushing SPACE i enter the ingame_screen. With ESC i come back to the start screen and again ESC to close the programm.
I missed that peace of code:

```
 def refresh_screen(self):
        pygame.display.flip()
        self.screen.blit(self.background, [0, 0])


def main_loop(self):
    while not GameState.end_game:
        while not GameState.start_screen:
            self.control()
            self.refresh_screen() #change picture
        self.splash_screen()
    pygame.quit()
```

here now full code (i got the pictures and the Orbitracer.ttf from Git link is in my question):

```
import pygame, random

RES = (800, 600)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

class GameState:
    pass

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.font.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode([RES[0], RES[1]])
        self.intro_font = pygame.font.Font(
            'data/Orbitracer.ttf', 72)
        self.intro_screen = pygame.image.load(
            '/home/pi/pivaders/data/graphics/start_screen.jpg')
        self.background = pygame.image.load(
            '/home/pi/pivaders/data/graphics/Space-Background.jpg')
        GameState.end_game = False
        GameState.start_screen = True


    def control(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                GameState.start_screen = False
                GameState.end_game = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN \
            and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                if GameState.start_screen:
                    GameState.start_screen = False
                    GameState.end_game = True
                else:
                    GameState.start_screen = True
        self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if self.keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            if GameState.start_screen:
                GameState.start_screen = False

    def splash_screen(self):
        while GameState.start_screen:
            self.screen.blit(self.intro_screen, [0, 0])
            self.screen.blit(self.intro_font.render(
                "PIVADERS", 1, WHITE), (175, 128))
            self.screen.blit(self.intro_font.render(
                "PRESS SPACE TO PLAY", 1, WHITE), (175, 191))
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.control()

    def refresh_screen(self):
        pygame.display.flip()
        self.screen.blit(self.background, [0, 0])

    def main_loop(self):
        while not GameState.end_game:
            while not GameState.start_screen:
                self.control()
                self.refresh_screen()
            self.splash_screen()
        pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pv = Game()
    pv.main_loop()
```